# Redux state not accessible in useEffect. How to prevent repetitive API calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Iam new to react and react-redux. What this code does is call /users/{id} endpoint on every PostItem which is a parent component and userDetails being a child of PostItem. The issue is a user may have multiple posts and so its repetitively calling the /users/{id} on multiple Posts which had same user(Author).

Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-voice-bb3oy5

I found 2 solutions to this exact issue and project here: https://ncoughlin.com/posts/react-redux-preventing-repetitive-api-requests/ but i was wondering is there a way to just do something like this:

```
 const { userId, user, users, fetchUser } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    const userAlreadyExists = () => {
      // logic to check if users state in redux already has the user(fetched Earlier with previous post)
    };
    if (!userAlreadyExists()) fetchUser(userId);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a common pattern to let redux fetch on mount:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const cachedUser = useSelector(state => state.usersById[userId]);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!cachedUser) {
        // async action will populate state.usersById[userId]
        // once the response has arrived and the reducer gets the payload.
        dispatch(fetchUser(userId));
    }
}, []);

// Render cachedUser below
```

If you want something more sophisticated (with a cache that expires for example), you'll need a bigger library that handles these concerns.